# callback function not being called

Tags: python, callback, ros

I'm implementing the code below:

```
class NavigationServer:

  def __init__(self, name):
    self._action_name = name
    self._as = actionlib.SimpleActionServer(self._action_name, 
    rodain_get_directions.msg.NavigateAction, 
    execute_cb=self.execute_cb, auto_start=False)
    self._as.start()

   def execute_cb(self, goal):
     rospy.loginfo("starting callback")
     self._as.set_succeeded()
```

Here is my client side:

```
def __goal_action_callback(data):

    rospy.loginfo(RobotMoving.get_name() + " " + "I heard {}".format(data))

    ac = SimpleActionClient("nav_server", NavigateAction)

    rospy.loginfo("goalCallback: Waiting for action server to start.")
    ac.wait_for_server()

    rospy.loginfo("goalCallback: Navigation service found.")

    goal = NavigateGoal()

    goal.target_pos = data

    ac.send_goal_and_wait(goal)

    if ac.get_state() == GoalStatus.SUCCEEDED:
        rospy.loginfo("Navigate action is completed!")
    else:
        rospy.loginfo("Navigate action failed!")
```

For some reason my `callback` function is not being called and messages aren't written in log file. Any idea why it is happening?
The client works fine.
   `SimpleActionServer` is a `ROS` method for initialize the server.

EDIT 1: Fixed callback expected parameters

EDIT 2: add main function

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  rospy.init_node("nav_server")

  rospy.loginfo("Starting navigation_server node")

  server = NavigationServer(rospy.get_name())
  rospy.spin()
```

EDIT 3: add __goal_action_callback call and client log file

```
def subscribe_to_topic(self, topic_name, topic_type):
    rospy.Subscriber(topic_name, topic_type, RobotMoving.__goal_action_callback) 

 uav.subscribe_to_topic("/directions", Point)

 [INFO] [1520695340.703649, 0.000000]: Waiting for service enable_motors
 [INFO] [1520695342.820296, 0.107000]: Turning on motors....
 [INFO] [1520695342.824292, 0.107000]: Navigation Client: Motors on
 [INFO] [1520695343.868810, 1.033000]: Navigation Client I heard x: 
 1.0
 y: 5.0
 z: 3.0
 [INFO] [1520695343.929997, 1.085000]: goalCallback: Waiting for 
 action server to start.
 [INFO] [1520695351.322910, 7.894000]: goalCallback: Navigation 
 service found.
 [INFO] [1520695351.323404, 7.894000]: Navigate action failed: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The `execute_cb` parameter of the constructor of `SimpleActionServer` defines a callback function taking a goal parameter. The [documentation](http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/actionlib/html/classactionlib_1_1simple__action__server_1_1SimpleActionServer.html#a16563f492135b8ee6e42e5311f9ab409) of the callback is not very good but a look into [source code](https://github.com/strawlab/ros_common/blob/master/actionlib/src/actionlib/simple_action_server.py#L294) will show the passed parameter.

To notify a client about success, you need to set the service as succeeded. A result is allowed to pass as optional parameter in this case.

Adding parameter and notify about success in your callback implementation should do the trick:

```
def execute_cb(self, goal):
    rospy.loginfo("starting callback")
    self.__as.set_succeeded()
```

Comment: Add the `callback parameter` ends on the same behavior

Comment: Do you call `rospy.spin()` after initializing `NavigationServer` and the action name is set correctly?

Comment: Yes, I call it. I added the main function which contains a call to rospy.spin on my question

Comment: Please also add the code you call `__goal_action_callback`.

Comment: Yes the function `__goal_action_callback` is there but where do you call it? To do start the action you need to call `__goal_action_callback` on client side. Server and client should be running in different nodes.

Comment: I also added the client log file. `__goal_action_callback` is the callback on [subscribe](http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/rospy/html/rospy.topics.Subscriber-class.html#__init__) to a topic

Comment: Works like expected: The action gets called but returns no success because you did not implement this. I've updated my answer.

Comment: The callback still not being invoking. Set `self._as.set_succeeded()` didn't change client evaluation and it still fail

Comment: Since `goalCallback: Navigation service found.` is logged, the service is available and should be called. Please make sure again `execute_cb` never gets called by setting a breakpoint or additional logging. I am not able to reproduce your problem.